# How to order all assets by their usage percentage in Coverage tab in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to sort the assets by their usage percentage in Coverage tab in Chrome DevTools?

Currently I can only sort by amount of unused bytes or usage visualization, like below:

[image]

So it is always difficult to pick out the 100% unused file manually.

Another issue is that whether I can add a column of "Used bytes"? Sometimes though it is indicate 100% unused, but the unused bytes is smaller than total bytes, which means there are still some bytes being used. With "Used bytes", I can accurately know whether 0 or several bytes are used.

Thanks.